# symbol not found for architecture i386

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I am facing the problem when integrate one project in another project in xCode for iPad. and throws the error like "symbol not found for architecture i386".

Comment: Is one project included as a static library?

Comment: @Manish: Please be more specific about how you have set up your project, how exactly you "integrate" the project. Your current description is far too short and incomplete for a serious answer.

Comment: If you have built something for ipad (which would be for ARM) it seems odd that you are trying to then include it in a i386 project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the project is not including one of the frameworks. Go to your Target -> Build Phases -> Link and verify that in fact you have all needed frameworks there.